# JSF in Enterprise Applications

Tags: jsf

Is JSF being used in the enterprise, or at least growing in use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're using it at my company in an 'Enterprise' way, I know the previous two companies I've worked at have used it in various projects. The only other framework which was more popular was Struts 1.

[This page](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Projects/RealWorldJSFLinks) gives some 'real world' JSF links.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's being used.

Is the use widespread? I don't think so. It's probably being used more than Wicket but less than Spring MVC, at least from conversations with my own peers.